# Cop chases in multiplayer

Tags: need-for-speed-most-wanted-2012

Is it possible to start a co-op/multiplayer cop chase? Can my friend and I evade the cops together? Are there  any cops at all in multiplayer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pursuit Mode is not in Multiplayer. You have the ability to create a playlist of Challenges/Races, but that is the extent of the game types.

Comment: Do cops appear at all in multiplayer?

Comment: From the time I've played multiplayer with PUGs and a friend, I have never seen even one.